# 「可変長なスタック，キュー」というデータ構造のプログラムを作成せよ

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    //??
} STACK;
typedef struct {
    //??
} QUEUE;
void push(STACK*, int);
int pop(STACK*);
void printSTACK(STACK*);
void put(QUEUE*, int);
int get(QUEUE*);
void printQUEUE(QUEUE*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i,n;
    //??
    //??
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("push %d\n", n);
        push(&s, n);
        printSTACK(&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("pop %d\n", pop(&s));
        printSTACK(&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("put %d\n", n);
        put(&q, n);
        printQUEUE(&q);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("get %d\n", get(&q));
        printQUEUE(&q);
    }
    return 0;
}
void push(STACK* s, int m)
{
    //??
}
int pop(STACK* s)
{
    //??
}
void printSTACK(STACK* s)
{
    //??
}
void put(QUEUE* q, int n)
{
    //??
}
int get(QUEUE* q)
{
    //??
}
void printQUEUE(QUEUE* q)
{
    //??
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node{
    int n;
    struct _node *next;
} node;
typedef struct {
        int n;
        int a[];
} STACK;
typedef struct {
        int n;
        int in;
        int out;
        int a[];
} QUEUE;
node *createnode(int);
void printnode(node*);
node *addHead(node*,int);
node *addHeadnode(node*,node*);
void push(STACK*, int);
int pop(STACK*);
void printSTACK(STACK*);
void put(QUEUE*, int);
int get(QUEUE*);
void printQUEUE(QUEUE*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i,n;
    STACK s;
    s.n=0;
    QUEUE q;
    q.in=0;
    q.out=0;
    q.n=0;
    node *p;
    p=NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("add %d\n", n);
        if(n<50)
        {
            p=addHead(p, n);
        }
        else
        {
            p=addTail(p, n);
        }
        printnode(p);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("push %d\n", n);
        push(&s, n);
        printSTACK(&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("pop %d\n", pop(&s));
        printSTACK(&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("put %d\n", n);
        put(&q, n);
        printQUEUE(&q);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("get %d\n", get(&q));
        printQUEUE(&q);
    }
    return 0;
}
void printnode(node *p)
{
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\t%d\n", p->n);
        p=p->next;
    }
}
node *createnode(int n)
{
    node *p=malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->n=n;
    p->next=NULL;
    return p;
}
node *addHead(node *p, int n)
{
    return addHeadnode(p,createnode(n));
}
node *addHeadnode(node *p, node *n)
{
    n->next=p;
    return n;
}
void push(STACK* s, int m)
{
    if(s->n>=N)return;
    s->a[s->n++]=m;
}
int pop(STACK* s)
{
    if(s->n<=0)return -1;
    return s->a[--s->n];
}
void printSTACK(STACK* s)
{
    int i;
    printf("\tn=%d\n", s->n);
    for(i=0;i<s->n;i++)
        printf("\ta[%d]=%d\n", i, s->a[i]);
}
void put(QUEUE* q, int n)
{
    if(q->n>=N)return;
    q->n++;
    q->a[q->in++]=n;
    if(q->in >= N)q->in=0;
}
int get(QUEUE* q)
{
    if(q->n<=0)return -1;
    q->n--;
    if(q->out>=N)q->out=0;
    return q->a[q->out++];
}
void printQUEUE(QUEUE* q)
{
    int i;
    printf("\tin=%d\n", q->in);
    printf("\tout=%d\n", q->out);
    for(i=q->out;;i++)
    {
        if(i>=N)i-=N;
        if(i==q->in)return;
        printf("\ta[%d]=%d\n", i, q->a[i]);
}
}
```

これの??が入っている部分を適切に回答する問題なのですが
まったくわかりません。下が自分で考えて書いたものですが。。。
教えてください

Comment: まったくわからないってことはないでしょうｗ？

Comment: 固定長なら出来るのですが
可変長ということで、おそらく記憶容量に対してノードを導入するんだろうと思いますが、構造でどのように定義するのかも分かりませんし、プッシュ等の部分をボイド型やイント型で表現するとなるともはやお手上げです。
お助けください。。。

Comment: まず`s`と`q`を宣言する必要があるのはわかりますよね？ リンクリストは学習済みですか？そうでなければ検索してみて下さい。スタックはリンクリストを前方に足し込む（既存のリストを新しいノードの後にする）、そして前方から取り出す。キューは、リンクリストの後方に付け足す、そして前方から取り出すということで良いと思います。プッシュ部分はボイド型では無くイント型ですね。

Comment: まあ、リンクリストを使うと限ったわけではないですけども。

Comment: 自分では下に追加したプログラムが精一杯ですが
ここまではあっていますか・・・？

Comment: `struct *next;` は間違いです。コンパイルできません。`//??` 以外の部分には自由に書くのは不可なんですかね？`STACK`, `QUEUE` とも無名構造体(タグ無し構造体)をtypedef してますから、自分自身へのポインタを内部に書くことができません。おそらくこの二つの前に`typedef struct node { int value; struct node *next;}NODE;` のようなものが必要でそれぞれがこの`NODE`のポインタを利用するような形になるように思います。

Comment: 頑張って作ってみました。
ただ、何が正しくて何がいけないのか分かりません。。。

Comment: 今気づきましたが、回答ありがとうございます！
どうなっているのか考えて考察してみたいと思います。

Comment: 構造体の最後に`int a[];`のようにして不定長の配列を実現することはできますが、これのための領域を動的に割り当てるためには、`STACK s;`ではなく`STACK *s;`のようにポインタである必要がありますが、`void push(STACK*, int);` のようなAPIを使用してサイズの拡張ができません。なので、ベクタを用いる実装にするためには、`int a[];` ではなく`int *a;`のようにポインタを使用する必要があります。

Comment: サイズ拡張のための別APIを作成してもいいならまた別ですけど。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リンクリストを用いた実装例

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> //time 関数のために必要

typedef struct {
    struct node {
        int value;
        struct node *next;
    } *list;
} STACK;

typedef struct {
    struct node *top, *tail;
} QUEUE;

void push(STACK*, int);
int pop(STACK*);
void printSTACK(STACK*);
void put(QUEUE*, int);
int get(QUEUE*);
void printQUEUE(QUEUE*);

int main(void){
    int i,n;
    STACK s = { NULL };
    QUEUE q = { NULL, NULL};

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("push %d\n", n);
        push(&s, n);
        printSTACK(&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("pop %d\n", pop(&s));
        printSTACK(&s);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%100;
        printf("put %d\n", n);
        put(&q, n);
        printQUEUE(&q);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("get %d\n", get(&q));
        printQUEUE(&q);
    }
    return 0;
}

void push(STACK* s, int m){
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->value = m;
    new_node->next = s->list;
    s->list = new_node;
}

int pop(STACK* s){
    if(s->list == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "stack is empty. can't pop\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    struct node *temp = s->list;
    s->list = temp->next;
    int ret_value = temp->value;
    free(temp);
    return ret_value;
}

void printSTACK(STACK* s){
    struct node *temp = s->list;

    while(temp){
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    puts("");
}

void put(QUEUE* q, int n){
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->value = n;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if(q->top == NULL){
        q->top = q->tail = new_node;
    } else {
        q->tail = q->tail->next = new_node;
    }
}

int get(QUEUE* q){
    if(q->top == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "queque is empty. can't get\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    struct node *temp = q->top;
    q->top = temp->next;
    int ret_value = temp->value;
    free(temp);
    return ret_value;
}

void printQUEUE(QUEUE* q){
    struct node *temp = q->top;

    while(temp){
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    puts("");
}
```